# Can I use environment variables in pubspec.yaml?

Tags: flutter, dart, continuous-integration, environment-variables, pubspec

I have private dependency from GitLab in my Flutter mobile app project. It is specified in `pubspec.yaml` with git repository link and I can successfully run `pub get` if I use ssh for it (I have generated ssh key and add it to my gitlab account)

```
  my_private_package:
    git:
      url: ssh://git@************/my_private_package.git
```

Now I want to build my app with AppCenter and deploy to stores. It is not possible to use ssh keys on AppCenter build phase, so the only working solution I see is to use [GitLab Deploy Token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/) as environment variable to access my private package from AppCenter machine. Git link to access the repository becomes this:

```
  my_private_package:
    git:
      url: https://gitlab+deploy-token-1:${DEPLOY_TOKEN}@************/my_private_package.git
```

Now, as far as I understand, pubspec can't resolve `DEPLOY_TOKEN` environment variable this way. `pub get` completes with error:

```
Git error. Command: `git clone --mirror https://gitlab+deploy-token-1:******@*******/my_private_package.git /Users/***/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/git/cache/my_private_package***`
stdout:                                                                 
stderr: Cloning into bare repository '/Users/***/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/git/cache/my_private_package***'...
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied                                       
remote: You must use a personal access token with 'read_repository' or 'write_repository' scope for Git over HTTP.
remote: You can generate one at https://*****/-/profile/personal_access_tokens
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.*****/my_private_package.git/'
exit code: 128
```

I also tried to use personal access tokens mentioned in error message above, but getting the same result. Although `git clone https://gitlab+deploy-token-1:${DEPLOY_TOKEN}@*******/my_private_package.git` from command line works fine if `DEPLOY_TOKEN` environment variable specified.

**My question:** Is it possible to use evnironment variables directly from `pubspec.yaml`? If no, how can I get my private package from another (not gitlab runner) CI machine?

Comment: Some alternatives: generate your `pubspec.yaml` file, or use [`path` dependencies](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#path-packages) with Git repositories that you fetch separately.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's not possible to set environment variables in pubspec.yaml as mentioned in this [thread](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/1358). As a workaround you can fetch the repository locally and [configure it as a path package](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#path-packages).